# finding a string and modifying content after the string in shell

Tags: shell

I have a variable in shell

```
vpp_dpdk_dev_conf="dev='name=a,pci=2,mtu=1400,num-rx-queues=64,num-tx-queues=64,num-rx-desc=8,num-tx-desc=8,skip=false|true
```

Now I have another file where pci will be present, as a sample

```
pci 2 {
        num-rx-queues 30
        num-tx-queues 17
}
```

Now if my pci value present then I need to replace whatever is present with what is present is env variable as string and if not present add them.

Now this pci can have multiple instances but need to replace which matches pci x.

I am parsing the entire string and remove the "=" as in final file it won't be present.

```
function conf_file_update()
{
    for param in $@
        do
            name=${param%%=*}
            value=${param#*=}
            echo "value final" $value
            if [ "$name" == "pci" ]; then
               named_param="$name $value"
               VAR=$(grep -n "${named_param}" $CONF_FILE_PATH | cut -d : -f 1)
               VAR=$(($VAR+1))
               echo $VAR
                sed -i '$VAR,$s/^        '"${name}"' [0-9]*/        '"${name}"' '"${value}"'/' $CONF_FILE_PATH
            fi
    done
}
read ra DEV <<< $vpp_dpdk_dev_conf
for i in "${DEV[@]}"; do
    #if [[ -f $i ]] && [[ -w $i ]]; then
    for param in $(IFS='=';echo $i); do
        echo $i
        name=${param%% *}
        value=${param#* }
        if [ "$name" == "pci" ]; then
             conf_file_update $DEV
             exit 0
```

In the sed command I am trying to pass the line number from which it should start to replace but sed is not taking the $VAR and saying

> unknown command: `V'

Any Suggestion in the approach in the problem is highly appreciated.
Thanks
Niladri

Comment: Your question is unclear. In your code, you use `$@`, but don't show how this script/function is called. Also you mention that you don't get the desired result, but don't say anything about what you actually get. Finally, I wonder whether you ever executed your code with `-x` turned on, as this would show you which statement produces an unexpected result.

Comment: Refined the question and the problem currently I am facing.

Comment: You are using single quotes in your `sed` command and therefore `$VAR` is not expanded by the shell. If you had used `set -x`, as I suggested in my comment, you would have seen this directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `$VAR`, and all `sed` expression, between `"` (not `'`).
Change your line:

```bash
sed -i '$VAR,$s/^        '"${name}"' [0-9]*/        '"${name}"' '"${value}"'/' $CONF_FILE_PATH
```

with:

```bash
sed -i "$VAR,\$s/^        ${name} [0-9]*/        ${name} ${value}/" "$CONF_FILE_PATH"
```